# Error in query using WHERE IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

This is the query I try to run:

```
Select Status from [transaction] where TransactionID IN (select MAX(CAST(TransactionID AS VARCHAR(36))), sum(debit) 
FROM [transaction]
WHERE  dbo.getday(StartSaleTime) >= '5/1/2011' and dbo.getday(StartSaleTime) <= '5/3/2011'  and Status > -1 And TransactionNo like 'EL%' And TransactionType = 4 
GROUP BY CustomerID, debit HAVING ( COUNT(CustomerID) > 1 ))
```

it returns this error:

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tells you exactly what is wrong in the error message. When using `in` you can only specify one column in the select list.

If you change your query to this, it should work fine.

```
Select Status from [transaction] where TransactionID 

IN (select MAX(CAST(TransactionID AS VARCHAR(36))) as [TransactionID]
FROM [transaction]
WHERE  dbo.getday(StartSaleTime) >= '5/1/2011' and dbo.getday(StartSaleTime) <= '5/3/2011'  and Status > -1 And TransactionNo like 'EL%' And TransactionType = 4 
GROUP BY CustomerID, debit HAVING ( COUNT(CustomerID) > 1 ))
```

You can specify multiple columns but only when using [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) not `IN`

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting two things and trying to use that with IN(). You should select only the ID when trying to do where someId In(list of Ids).

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery has to return only a single field. Right now you're returning two, so the overall query looks kinda like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE TransactionID IN ((a,b), (c,d), etc...)
```

SQL server doesn't known which column to use for the `IN` stuff, so it's complaining.